# Exec_bad iphone..program terminates

Tags: iphone

I developed one small application in objective c++ program uses socket connection from server.so I performed status of socket like(connecting , connected,failed to make connection). In that I have 2 display option onw with activity indicator another with uilabel to tell what happen to socket or status of socket but only uiactivity indicator is working well.If I put label.text=@"something",it just goes error.

Comment: WAY to little information to go on.

Answer (score -1):

Have you made sure that you've hooked up all the Interface Builder things correctly with the label?